# When running jasmine tests, how can I know if I am in a describe block, beforeEach block or it block?

Tags: javascript, testing, tdd, jasmine, spy

I need to throw an exception if a utility is used outside of an 'it' or 'beforeEach' block in my tests.
Example -

```
   describe('some test', function(){

     useUtil();     // should throw exception

     beforeEach(function(){
        useUtil()   // should work
     })

     it('should test something', function(){
        useUtil()   // should work
     }) 
   })
```

The util creates spies, and I want to make sure they are created in a way that allows Jasmine to clean them after every suite.

Comment: You can't know that (at runtime). You could statically analyze the code but that seems to be more effort than it's worth.

Comment: You _may_ be able to hack something by throwing and catching an exception in `useUtil` and inspecting the `stack` property of the thrown `Error`. `stack` is non-standard though, so behaviour would not be consistent across runtimes.

Comment: please check jasmine docs for spieses: http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Spies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a globally accessible variable called `isSpecPhase`, and set it initially to `false`.

Then, define a global beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    isSpecPhase = true;
});
```

Make sure to define the `beforeEach` before all your other suites, so that it runs before each of your specs.
In your util function, you could then check if `isSpecPhase === true`, and throw an exception otherwise.